# Can one domain be hosted on two drupal instances?

Tags: 8

I have a huge Drupal 6 site, and a small, newer partial version of the site on Drupal 8. Instead of migrating, we decided to build a brand new site from scratch.

Is it possible to host the site such that:

http://www.sitename.com takes user to --> new D8 site

http://www.sitename.com/topic1 /topic2 takes user to new site.

http://www.sitename.com/topic3 /topic4 (everything else) takes user to old D6 site?

Thanks!

Comment: I hope you are aware that D6 is no longer supported; therefore, D6 will never ever get any security updates from drupal.org. So /topic4 (everything else)  will potentially be vulnerable to getting hacked.

Comment: Yes, and we're rapidly moving to D8. But it's a huge site, and there's a lot of custom modules to move so, unfortunately, we do have to keep it for now.

Comment: What webserver are you running? nginx, apache?

Comment: We're running Apache.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a reverse proxy for this, both Apache and Nginx support this. What you do is that you make the Drupal 6 site available on a different URL. This might be even a local url, like sitename2.local. Add this to the hosts file on your server (/etc/hosts on Linux) and point it to 127.0.0.1. Make sure you set up a virtual host in your webserver to point sitename2.local to the root directory of your Drupal 6 site.

By using a reverse proxy you tell your webservice to forward calls to /topic/4 to sitename2.local/topic/4 and return it to the user, just like a proxy. In Nginx it should look something like:

```
location /topic/4 {
    proxy_pass http://sitename2.local/topic/4;
}
```

For Apache you need to enable the proxy modules:

```
> a2enmod
> proxy proxy_ajp proxy_http rewrite deflate headers proxy_balancer proxy_connect proxy_html
```

Your virtual host file should look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass /topic/4 http://sitename2.local/topic/4
    ProxyPassReverse /topic/4 http://sitename2.local/topic/4
    (...)
</VirtualHost>
```

If you Google around for reverse proxy you will find tons of information on how to exactly configure them.